# Как в Java создать документ для настольного приложения

Tags: java, apache-poi

Всем доброго времени суток!
В электронной таблице, например MS Excel, можно создать электронную копию документа любой сложности для последующего автоматизированного его заполнения.
Вопрос, - какими средствами создаётся такой же документ в Java для последующего автоматизированного его заполнения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно JasperReports то, что вам нужно.
А еще есть Apache POI.